# C# WPF Group datagrid by keywords in data

Tags: c#, wpf

Inside viewmodel, I defined a ObservableCollection and bind it with the data grid;

```
AllData = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(_allData);
```

But now I need to group the data in the view but not via the column header. I need to group by the content in the datagrid:

For example, I have column A,B,C,D,E,F, If ColumnA.Content contains keyword1, it is  Group1, else if ColumnB and ColumnC are not empty, it is group2, else if ColumnD contains keyword2, it is group3...

How can I grouping like this?

Thanks!

Eva

Comment: Calculate the group you want for each row into a column.  Add a column - say - GroupColumn. Then process the data using your logic and set GroupColumn to 1, 2, 3 or whatever. Then you can group by GroupColumn.

Comment: Hi Andy, nice idea!! I am really new to C# and WPF, can you give me any reference if i want to add a column based on the row content in viewmodel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grouping relies on columns in your collectionview. The simplest way to approach this ( and simple is particularly good if you're a newbie ) is to add another public property to whatever the class is you have in _allData.

Let's assume for a moment this is RowVM ( short for row viewmodel ).

Hence _allData is an ObservableCollection.

We want to group on something so add another public property to RowVM.  It seems this will be an int so you want something like:

```
public class RowVM : BaseViewModel
    {
    public int GroupColumn { get; set; } = 0;
    public string A { get; set; }
    public string B { get; set; }
    public string C { get; set; }

    }
```

It is preferable for anything you bind to implement inotifypropertychanged ( seem msdn documentation if this is a new idea ).  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/how-to-implement-property-change-notification This is the case even if your code doesn't raise property changed anywhere.

You will want to do this with every viewmodel so you want a base class does that stuff and you don't repeat your code.

Hence I inherit from a BaseViewModel.

Here is an example:

```
public class BaseViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

That's just got auto getter and setters.  Maybe this should be a propfull with a private backer and raise property changed when the value changes from the setter.

You need to populate that somehow so you, obviously, want a loop of some sort.

You could do that using linq and .ForEach() executing some code in the foreach or a for loop or a foreach loop.

Whichever you choose.

You want a bit of code in there which implements your logic and sets the value

Something like:

```
        foreach (var row in _allData)
        {
            if (row.A.Contains(keyword1))
            {
                row.GroupColumn = 1;
                continue;
            }
            if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(row.B) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(row.B))
            {
                row.GroupColumn = 3;
                continue;
            }
            row.GroupColumn = 2;
        }
```